# Запуск скрипта python с флагом "-i" по умолчанию

Tags: python, cmd, консоль

Имеется скрипт `test.py`, при нажатии на который открывается CMD, выполняется скрипт и окно закрывается.
Хотелось бы, чтобы после выполнения консоль оставалась в режиме интерпретатора.

Можно конечно создать bat файл с:

```
python -i test.py
```

Но хочется, чтобы всё было просто по открытию. Так будет удобней.

Comment: Это разные вещи, при "input('any press key')" я просто увижу, что мне вывела консоль. А я хочу продолжить вызывать функции.
"python -i test.py" - вот, что я хочу получить при двойном щелчке по скрипту.

Comment: А если создать .bat  с python -i test.py ?

Comment: вы хотите REPL в конце запустить? `import code; code.interact()` или (по вкусу) `from ptpython.repl import embed
embed(globals(), locals())`

Comment: чтобы добавить аргумент в командную строку, можно скрипт перезапустить  с помощью `os.execl()` [Is it possible to set the python -O (optimize) flag within a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7527055/4279)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого в windows есть Doskey.
Инструкция тут: https://dataart.ru/news/windows-aliasy-komandnoj-stroki/